# Database migration fails in entrypoint.sh during docker-compose up

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker and trying to dockerize the project I am working on, which is a simple Symfony API with a MySql database.

I want docker to execute the DB migration `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` when it builds the container, so I added an [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to do so:

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#create or update db
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction

# start apache
apache2-foreground
```

Then when I run `docker-compose up -d` everything works fine but database **is not migrated**. When I enter the container I can manually execute the `doc:mig:mig` command but how do I get this done automatically? Am I not understanding the usage of entrypoint properly?

Here is my **docker-compose.yaml** file (substituted sensitive data)

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    api:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        links:
            - db
        volumes:
            - C:/Repos/myProjectName/src:/var/www/myProjectName_api/src
    db:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: myUserName
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: myPwd
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myRootPwd
            MYSQL_DATABASE: dev_myProjectName
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
```

and my **Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.1-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libzip-dev git wget nano --no-install-recommends \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/2.4.2/composer.phar \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/bin/composer
COPY docker/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
COPY . /var/www/myProjectName_api

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/myProjectName_api/var

# Allow Authorization header
RUN echo 'SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

COPY environments/.env.dev /var/www/myProjectName_api/.env.local

WORKDIR /var/www/myProjectName_api

COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /tmp
RUN chmod +x /tmp/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /tmp/entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: When you say "Everything works fine", what does that mean? Also, check the logs in the API container for any errors.

Comment: Hi @HansKilian, when I say "everything works fine" I mean both services are running, I can reach port 8000 and all of my API endpoints but I get a Doctrine exception of tables not found, due to DB being still empty. Where are the API container logs located?

Comment: Do `docker ps` to find the name of the api container. Then do `docker logs <container-name>`.

Comment: I see the corresponding error log: It is a `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` error. Could it be possible that when entrypoint.sh is executed, the db service is still not created?

Comment: Docker compose starts both containers at the same time, so it's very possible that the database isn't ready to accept connections when the migration starts. Adding `depends_on` is probably not enough, since that will only make docker compose wait until the database container is started before it starts the api container. It can't wait until the database is ready for connections. A simple solution could be to add `sleep 30` to your entrypoint script.